# Inline Babel script:24 Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs

New to ReactJS, can not understand why I am getting `Inline Babel script:24 Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function`.

```
componentDidMount(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/mvn-spring-list/list"

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        return this.setState({ listItem: data })

    }).bind(this)
}
```

Header:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script src="react.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.16.8.6.development.js"></script>
    <script src="babel.7.5.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-with-ajax-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
</head>
```

Do I need to add any special JS library?
Or the  $.getJSON not supported anymore?

Comment: Complete code here -  https://github.com/crsardar/HandsOnWebTech/blob/master/react-webpages/react-rest-api-interaction.html

Answer (score 0):

Please get familiar with axios or fetch library its common way to fetch data from server in React applications.

Comment: First i like to learn plain JS, jQuery, ReactJS. after that any specific library

Comment: if you learn React simply skip jQuery they are a different approach. Axios or Fetch are really easy to use so if you want make http.get its simply easiest way to do.